# Finite 2-player game with a unique pure–mixed Nash equilibrium

Tags: game-theory

I am trying to construct a normal-form game satisfying *all* of the following conditions:

- there are two players;
- each player has a finite number of strategies;
- there is a *unique* Nash equilibrium, in which
- one of the players uses a pure strategy; and
- the other player uses a non-degenerate mixed strategy.

I have put considerable effort into trying to construct an example, but I keep finding that if a pure–mixed Nash equilibrium exists, then there exist other Nash equilibria as well. I am actually wondering if it is possible to construct an example with a unique such Nash equilibrium.

If this is not possible, I am wondering how to prove the following implication of this:

> Let $\Gamma$ be a normal-form game with two players. The strategy sets are $S_1$ and $S_2$, each of which is a non-empty finite set. If $(\sigma_1^*,\sigma_2^*)\in\Delta(S_1)\times\Delta(S_2)$ is a Nash equilibrium of this game such that
>
> - $\sigma_1^*(s_1)=1$ for some $s_1\in S_1$; and
> - $\sigma_2^*(s_2)<1$ for all $s_2\in S_2$,
>
> then there exist other Nash equilibria.

Any feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: Intuitively, the player with the mixed strategy knows what the other player is going to play so they should pick the best response to it. Either that's one particular move, or if there are several best responses which yield the same results. The only reason their best response could be mixed is if there are several, in which case they can choose them with any probabilities, so it is not unique

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I see your point, but it is possible that for the player that is playing the pure strategy, this pure strategy is a best response _only_ if the other player uses a particular mixed strategy. For example, consider the game: $$\begin{array}{cc}(4,0)&(0,1)\\(0,1)&(4,0)\\(2,1)&(2,1)\end{array}$$ In this case, the row player’s bottom action is a best reply _only_ if the column player mixes with probabilities $1/2-1/2$. (Yet, there are other Nash equilibria in this game, so uniqueness breaks down after all, but for a different reason.)

Comment: Yes you are right, it is not that simple.

Comment: It is not possible, so you should focus on proving that. Sorry don't have time to write a full proof.

Comment: @RahulSavani Thank you, after a lot of experimentation, I, too, suspect that this is the case. I definitely understand you are busy, yet I would be extremely grateful if you could just enumerate the main points of the argument you have in mind. I could fill out the details myself.

Comment: @triple_sec: Sorry, I was too quick to comment. I actually tried to work through my proof idea, but it ends with needing a complicated case analysis. It's certainly not easy to construct an example, and I would still conjecture it is probably not possible (though in general a unique equilibrium with unequal size supports may be, but it seems that one being pure is a big constraint). Nice question - upvoted! Will return if I learn more. BTW, you may find my online bimatrix solver useful for exploring this: http://cgi.csc.liv.ac.uk/~rahul/bimatrix_solver/.

Comment: @RahulSavani Thank you for your thoughtful comment! I worked with the bimatrix solver you linked before and, in my experience, it produces incorrect results sometime, so I am reluctant to rely on it anymore. However, a Wolfram Mathematica code downloadable [here](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/2014/03/using-reduce-to-compute-nash-equilibria/) does the same thing, it’s pretty awesome!

Comment: @triple_sec: I only put that solver online last week, so probably it was the original one at banach.lse.ac.uk that you had problems with before (they look almost identical, and the banach.lse.ac.uk now points to this new one).  Sorry about earlier errors. The problems were not with the underlying solvers (1. for finding extreme equilibria using lrs; 2. for finding with those the equilibrium components) but with text parsing due to changes in some python libraries that were updated by server admins. I have fixed the obvious problem and welcome feedback. Thanks for the pointer to the other code.